# Can't return more than one param on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have a project where I use Node/Express for the API and Angular in the front end.

I have an endpoint where I want to return more than one field to populate an error message.

Here is the current .post code I have:

```
router.route('/')
.post(function(req, res) {

  User.findOne({
    login: req.body.login
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
 
    if (!user) {
      res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      console.log('User' + user.confirmed)
      // check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch && !err) {

          if(user.confirmed){
            // if user is found and password is right create a token
            var token = jwt.encode(user, config.secret);
            // return the information including token as JSON
            res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
          } else {
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'In order to login, you must first confirm you email. A confirmation email was sent to ' + user.email })
          }

        } else {
          res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

On "success: false" I want to return an error message title and the error message, which I will then display in Angular.

I tried using "res.json" as well as "res.send".

I added a "title" field to my response, like this:

```
 res.json({success: false, title:'Email confirmation needed', msg: 'In order to login, you must first confirm you email. A confirmation email was sent to ' + user.email })
              }
```

But when I tried to access it on the angular side using "err.title" and "err.msg" it is undefined.

Here is my angular controller:

```
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, localStorageService, SweetAlert, AuthService){

  $scope.user = {
    name: '',
    password: ''
  };
 
  $scope.login = function() {
    AuthService.login($scope.user).then(function(msg) {
      $state.go('dashboard');
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('There was an error:', err);

      SweetAlert.swal({
          title: 'Login Error',
          text: err,
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
          confirmButtonText: 'Retry',
          closeOnConfirm: true
      }, function() { $state.go('login'); });

    });
  };


});
```

Comment: You could please show the angular code. I think you have a .data missing

Comment: The AngularJS counter-part code is missing

Comment: Manuel, I tried err.data.[field], but id didn't work.

Comment: you may be missing the http error code, is it returning `http200` even when there's an error?